# JSON/LD Breadcrumbs & Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to create a breadcrumb JSON-LD tag which can fire dynamically using Google Tag Manager.

I know the elements which I’d need to get to fire dynamically and these are listed below. The code on my page already had a non SCHEMA/JSON based tag which isn’t pulling into Google.

It’s been created using a simple ul li function and I wanted to see if there is a custom JS variable that could be used to say for Position 1 take the first li item and dynamically pull this back in GTM.

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
 "itemListElement":
 [
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 1,
   "item":
   {
    "@id": "https://example.com/dresses", - Dynamic 
    "name": "Dresses"- Dynamic
    }
  },
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 2,
  "item":
   {
     "@id": "",- Dynamic
     "name": "Real Dresses"- Dynamic
   }
  }
 ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a custom variable within GTM that uses a CSS selector to get the bit you need from the page and then use it within the JSON-LD tag - can't say anything more specific without knowing the structure of your HTML. You can see something similar done here [Dynamic JSON-LD with GTM](https://moz.com/blog/using-google-tag-manager-to-dynamically-generate-schema-org-json-ld-tags) and hopefully you can adapt it to suit your needs.

Comment: When you link to another page, you should also include the important bits in your answer.